# Move a file to other drive via Cygwin/UNIX ($ cp -R ..)

Tags: unix, cygwin, processing, cp, leap-motion

Its my first time working with cygwin so bear with me please.

I need to install a processing library via cygwin in order for it to work.
I followed all the steps in this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZlj0ZZe8Fw) and in the last step (00:22 seconds mark) I need to "cp" LeapMotion to the directory where Processing stores it's librarys.

I store mine in "D:\Processing Sketches\libraries" and i don't know how to copy it there. I'm confused with the ~/home/ part.
I tried "$ cp -R LeapMotion /D:/Processing\ Sketches/libraries/" but that doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under cygwin DOS drive letters are mapped to `/cygdrive/<drive>`, so you would do it like this:

```
$ cp -R LeapMotion /cygdrive/d/Processing\ Sketches/libraries/
```

Comment: Thanks, i would never have gotten there without your help :)